# Accessing the character in the line below

Tags: point, tabs, characters

I am writing an Emacs Lisp function which needs to know the character directly under `point` in the line below, returning `nil` when no such character exists. I thus defined the function `char-below`, which seems to work well except that it breaks down in case the line below has tabs.

```
(defun char-below ()      
  (condition-case nil
      (aref
        (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position 2) (line-end-position 2))
        (- (point) (line-beginning-position)))
    (error nil)))
```

Is there a built-in elisp function to accomplish this?  If not, is there a cleverer way to write `char-below`, accounting for the presence of tabs?

---

EDIT:  I tried a solution based on `next-line` but there seems to be a problem with using `next-line` in Lisp code, as observed in its doc-string:

> *"This function is for interactive use only; in Lisp code use `forward-line` instead."*

A way to illustrate the problem is by defining the following key-binding, using the `char-below` function proposed by Erik Sjöstrand, which is supposed to display the character below in the message area and move forward one char.

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "<f12>")
   (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (message (char-below))
     (forward-char)))
```

Curiously, repeated pressed of the key f12 thus defined keep messaging the same character below the position point was at the time of the FIRST invocation of f12.

I think this is because  `next-line` uses goal columns, and somehow the goal column is not updated when the above key is repeated.

---

EDIT 2

By the way, Erik initially proposed the  function `char-below` as follows

```
(defun char-below ()
  (ignore-errors
    (save-excursion
      (next-line)
      (string (following-char)))))
```

and this is the function that causes the error I mentioned above.  Since then Eric has edited his function inserting the command
`(setq temporary-goal-column nil)` which fixes this issue.

Comment: (Don't quote lambdas.)

Comment: comment deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I haven't tested it with tabs though...

```
(defun char-below ()
  (setq temporary-goal-column nil) 
  (ignore-errors
    (save-excursion
      (next-line)
      (string (following-char)))))
```

If you want it to return `nil` when there's no char below, because the row below is shorter than the current position, this is a modification:

```
(defun char-below ()
  (setq temporary-goal-column nil) 
  (ignore-errors
    (save-excursion
      (next-line)
      (unless (eolp)
        (string (following-char))))))
```

It also returns `nil` when the char at the row below is the end of the line, which might not be what you want.

Comment: If you want the char, and not the string, just remove the `string` function.

Comment: Dear @Erik,  please see the last part of my question, which I added as a consequence of your answer.

Comment: The problem was with `temporary-goal-column`. If you don't want to use `next-line`, you can use `line-move-visual` or `line-move`.

Comment: Thanks @Erik, setting `temporary-goal-column` to `nil` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```el
(defun char-below ()
  (let ((col  (current-column)))
    (save-excursion
      (if (not (zerop (forward-line 1)))
          nil
        (move-to-column col)
        (and (not (eolp))  (char-after))))))
```

But you don't say what you mean by "*it breaks down in case the line below has tabs*" or "*accounting for the presence of tabs*".

If you want to consider that any tab chars present are in fact replaced by space chars, then you can use `move-to-column` with optional arg `FORCE` to convert tab chars to spaces.  In that case you'll need to also undo that change if you don't want it to persist.

Another thing unclear about your question: you ask for the character (which the code here gives you), but the code you supply doesn't even try to return the character - it tries to return its position.

Comment: An alternative to `move-to-column` could be `line-move-to-column`, which will return `nil` if we end up inside a tab character.

Comment: @ErikSjöstrand: 1. It's not clear what behavior is requested when there is a tab char. 2. `line-move-to-column` ignores invisible text. Is that good or bad here? Nothing in the question says it should (or should not) be ignored.

Comment: Hi @Drew,  thanks for your answer.  I did not know about the built-in functions `current-column` and `move-to-column`, which essentially solve my problem.

Comment: @Drew,  regarding your comment about my code returning the position rather than the character, you might not have noticed the call do `aref` on the string built with `buffer-substring`.

Comment: @Drew,  my code does not work if there are tabs on the line below in a column to the left of `point`, due to my naive application of `aref`, but with `move-to-column` the problem disappears.  Thanks.